# Python Duplicate Excel Solver Set Objective Function to Value Of

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver

I've been using the Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximation `scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla` routine in scipy to minimize my objective function with two non-negative constraints and it works well most of the time, but I have a problem when I don't have proper starting values for the two variables - which happens more often than not.

```
def constraint1(x):
    return x[0]

def constraint2(x):
    return x[1]

def objective(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]; # not actual objective function

x0 = [1.2, 3]
result = fmin_cobyla(objective, x0, [constraint1, constraint2])
```

I usually test my optimization routines using Excel as a second set of eyes, which led to me finding out about the Set Objective f(n) to Value Of: 0 option in Solver. Is this something that I can easily duplicate in Scipy.Optimize or am I making this too complicated? Since my actual objective function is trying to minimize the sum of squared differences, my goal would be to stop the optimization routine if/when it gets as close as possible to 0.

Comment: If you're trying to minimize the sum of squared differences, the objective cannot be negative, so you can just leave it unbounded.  Otherwise, you can always add your objective as an inequality constraint to bound it to its desired value.  Generally, as in this case, that's not really what you want to do though.

Comment: @RobFalck After doing some research, I think what I'm looking for is a root solver, such as scipy.optimize.fsolve(), where I try to solve f(x)=0 making sure x[0] and x[1] are non-negative. Although even though I think this is the right approach, I'm still stuck on how to get that working with constraints.

Comment: Just remember that, depending on the number of degrees of freedom you have, you may not be able to achieve f(x)=0.  You're basically minimizing the squared residual value, and having r-squared by nonzero isn't necessarily a bad thing, it just represents the best possible fit with the given data.